# Autolayout, Core Graphics and CALayer. Get the right autolayout-calculated bounds

Tags: ios, core-graphics, autolayout, calayer

I've a problem trying to "manually" draw a view using CAlayers and Autolayout.
I need to know the size that the view in which I'm going to attach layers will get after autolayout is calculated.
Initially I've used as starting point for my settings the layoutSubviews function, but this is not the right solution since 
it is called more then one time and if I get bounds inside this function i obtain different results:

```
     LINE FRAME {{0, 0}, {600, 225}} // AUTO LAYOUT NOT YET CALCULATED
     LINE FRAME {{0, 0}, {320, 225.5}} // AUTO LAYOUT CALCULATED
```

**My question is:** which is the best way to manually draw views (using Core Graphics or CALayer) in relation with Autolayout? 
is there a way to know that Autolayout has been calculated and the view is ready for the "final size" and eventually, is there a way to 
know that autolayout has changed and so the view needs to be redrawn?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it inside of drawRect? I'm assuming you are using a custom UIView since you said layoutSubviews instead of viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Is this a good place for CALayer drawing too? I've always used drawRect for Core Graphics only

Comment: Please fill an answer with your comment if you think it could be a solution.